# How to retrieve content type from a MAPI Imessage

Tags: c++, com, atl, mapi

i am new to MAPI programming. i am trying to check if a MAPI Imessage (c++ IUnknown object) is encrypted or not, if i have a mime in hand i will check for the content type, but what to check for in MAPI IMessage object? 
i have seen PR_X400_CONTENT_TYPE property, i am not sure if this is the desired property, because i am not able to get it using IMessage::GetProps function. i tried using the following code:

```
SizedSPropTagArray(9, mcols) = { 9, { PR_MESSAGE_CLASS, PR_SENDER_NAME, PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS, PR_RTF_IN_SYNC, PR_RECEIVED_BY_EMAIL_ADDRESS, PR_RECEIVED_BY_NAME, PR_RECEIVED_BY_ENTRYID, PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS, PR_X400_CONTENT_TYPE } };
ULONG pcount; SPropValue *props = 0; HRESULT hr;
hr = message->GetProps((SPropTagArray*)&mcols, 0, &pcount, &props);
if (props[8].ulPropTag == PR_X400_CONTENT_TYPE) {
// not going here
}
```

but its not returning this specific property. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAPI does not store the content type since MIME is not a native storage for MAPI. Use the PR_MESSAGE_CLASS property - it will be IPM.NOTE.SMIME.MultipartSigned.* for the signed messages and 
IPM.NOTE.SMIME.* for the encrypted messages.